# How to render Vray objects in 3ds max faster?

Tags: rendering, 3dsmax

How can i get good quality scene with 3ds max using Vray materials in shorter time?
Rendering a night scene is taking too long, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

As it was said before, you really just need to learn all the parameters.  My general rules below apply to architectural TEST renderings, but there is much more to add and explore and I have just started to accept that non test renderings will take a few hours.

For Faster Tests:

**Indirect Illumination Tab**:

**Global Illumination**: Use **Irradiance Map** and **Light Cache**.  Brute Force takes forever and sometimes Photon Map seems to eat up memory.

**Irradiance Map**: set to Low and reduce the Hemespheric Subdivisons as well as the Samples (the only 2 things that should still be selectable if you select "low"), when ready for a higher level rendering, set it to only medium and increase the subdivisions and samples.

**Light Cache**: set the subdivisions to approximately your resolution.  IE if you are doing a 800x600 rendering make the subs 800, if you need a faster rendering cut this number in half, ie 400.

Make sure that caustics are off

**Settings Tab:**

**DMC Sampler**: set your noise threshold to .1, this makes your render have a ton of noise, but really decreases rendering time.  Reset it to .01 or smaller when you want to make a serious render.

**Settings**: Set Render Region Divison to 32 for a faster render, when you want a higher level rendering reset it to 64

If renderings still take forever set all your materials to just a base VRay Material with a diffuse grey color and see if that helps.  If it does you have some materials that take up too much space/are too complex.  If the materials are fine but you still have trouble try turning off your lights, and increasing the environment (skylight) override from 1.0 to something like 6.0.  If that helps then it was your lighting that was causing the huge rendering time.

Also also, if its not in the rendering view TURN IT OFF.

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to control it, learn every parameter, what it affects. don't just press render and expect everything to magically become fast and look good.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [rendering via console](http://free.windows9download.net/download/3ds-vray-command-line-render.html).